# Multiple image upload, resize and saveinto db using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to upload multiple image using codeigniter. here is the scenario
[image]

How can i upload multiple image and save image location into db (cause i want to show uploaded image in my view file) and before upload I also want to rename my images and resize them into 'thumb' size.

here is my controller:

```
    function uploadRoomImage(){

    $i = 0;
    $files = array();
    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value['name']))
        {

            $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/upload/rooms/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
            $config['file_name'] = $filename;
            $config['max_size'] = '2000';
            $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
            $config['overwrite'] = false;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            }
            else
            {
                $files[$i] = $this->upload->data();
                $i++;

                //load image library
                $this->load->library('image_lib');

                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path'];
                $config['new_image'] = $image_data['file_path'].'room_thumb/';
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumb';
                // $config['overwrite'] = false;
                $config['width'] = 280;
                $config['height'] = 280;

                //initialize upload library using the config settings defined above.
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->image_lib->display_errors());
                } else {
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                }
                //i want send each image file location into db in here after resizing each image
            }
        }           
    }
```

i can upload multiple image but i cann't send their location into my db and i cannt resize them also. plz help

Comment: first get all the files from the users store them in a temp folder. then one by one you can resize them and move them to your desired folder location. and after move is complete you can save the path of the moved folder into db.

Comment: @justrohu i have edited my code please give a look and now i can upload multiple image but i cann't send their location into my db and i cannt resize them also.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path'];` misses the file name attached to the full path. You should also include that for the `$config['new_image']`.

And if you want to upload the data to your database, you could probably [create a model](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) which handles that operation.